# Mysql event with variable working only parly

Tags: mysql, events

My event runs fine for the first part; but the 2nd part doesnt work.. what am I missing here? I am a little new to working with variables.

```
SELECT max(id) from scanner_raw into @maximale;

insert ignore into scanner
select 
datetime,
scanvalue
from scanner_raw where id <= @maximale;

delete from scanner_raw where id <= @maximale;
```

The insert part works well, the delete part doesnt seem to do anything. What am I missing? What I run these sql's from phpmyadmin the delete part also works..

Comment: One obscure possibility is that an insert trigger on the `scanner` table uses the same `@maximale` user-defined variable and is stomping your value.  Also, check the error log (`SELECT @@ERROR_LOG` to find the path to this file) to see if your event is throwing an error.

Comment: @Alex van Es, I had an answer ready for the question you just deleted. You can find it [here](http://pastebin.com/DULninjH).